# Data is not fetched from Feature file

Tags: cucumber

I have written Feature file which i have used Example keyword. In that one of the input is not getting passed onto input field.

I have tried changing the parameter in scenario Outline.

Feature File:

- Feature: Login  to Newtours website

  - A number of user should be able to login into newtours with multiple username and password provided
- Scenario Outline: Login to account with credentials

  - Given User navigates to ""

    - And User click on Register button
    - And User enters "" firstname
    - And User enters "" lastname
    - And User enters "" Phone
    - And User enters "" emailaddress
    - And User enters "" address
    - And User enters "" city
    - And User enters "" State
    - And User enters "" Postalcode
    - And User selects country india
    - And User enters "" username
    - And User enters "" password
    - And User enters "" Confirmpassword
    - When user submits Login button
    - Then the user should be successfully registered.

Examples:

```
|    URL                               | FirstName          | LastName           | Phone               `      | Email               | Address           | City        | State       | Postalcode       | Username       | Password     |  ConfirmPassword     |
|http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/      |   user1            |      Name1         | 80897654321                | user1@gmail.com     | 1 Street          | Bengaluru   | Karnataka   | 560059           | User1          |  123         |    123               | 
|http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/      |   user2            |      Name2         | 80897654322                | user2@gmail.com     | 2 Street          | Bengaluru   | Karnataka   | 560059           | User2          |  133         |    133               |
|http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/      |   user3            |      Name3         | 80897654323                | user3@gmail.com     | 3 Street          | Bengaluru   | Karnataka   | 560059           | User3          |  143         |    143               |
|http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/
```

The phone number provided should come in input of website but the keyword "Phone" is coming

Answer (score 0):

I see a tick mark in the Example header column, right after `Phone`.  If that's actually in your feature file, it might not be parsing correctly.

If that's not it, I would check the regex in the step definition.  Maybe the "Phone" you're seeing is the last word of the step binding (`And User enters "" Phone`) being captured as part of the parameter due to some faulty regex.

Answer (score 0):

It shall be because in scenario outline you keeping heading as `Phone` but under Example where we actually pass inputs associated with headings, there you should have `Phone` not `` Phone \` `` so please remove `` ` `` just after Phone heading in Example.

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you accept the answer as it would be helpful for other members

Comment: I edited the question so that this formatting error is no longer present. I am unsure if it was significant. Given the poor overall formatting in the original question, I would perhaps be slightly skeptical that this actually solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Feature: Login to Newtours website A number of user should be able to login into newtours with multiple username and password provided

Scenario Outline: 
Login to account with credentials Given User navigates to "" 
And User click on Register button And User enters "" firstname And User enters "" lastname 
And User enters "" Phone And User enters "" emailaddress And User enters "" address And User enters "" city 
And User enters "" State And User enters "" Postalcode And User selects country india 
And User enters "" username And User enters "" password And User enters "" Confirmpassword 
When user submits Login button Then the user should be successfully registered.

Examples: 
| URL | FirstName | LastName | Phone | Email | Address | City | State | Postalcode | Username | Password | ConfirmPassword | 
|http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/ | user1 | Name1 | 80897654321 | user1@gmail.com | 1 Street | Bengaluru | Karnataka | 560059 | User1 | 123 | 123 | 
|http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/ | user2 | Name2 | 80897654322 | user2@gmail.com | 2 Street | Bengaluru | Karnataka | 560059 | User2 | 133 | 133 | 
|http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/ | user3 | Name3 | 80897654323 | user3@gmail.com | 3 Street | Bengaluru | Karnataka | 560059 | User3 | 143 | 143 |